# Spend about 8 hours after arriving in Bangalore early in the morning

Tags: bangalore, blr

I will arrive in Bangalore airport around 3 am. My hotel doesn't allow me to check in before 12 pm. What options do I have for me to rest if I want to just stay in airport to wait? Is there any lounge in airport for arrival travelers?

Comment: Book the hotel from a day earlier and ask if you can check in very late?

Comment: Don't worry, with the bangalore traffic, you will reach city only by 12. :D

Answer (score 1):

The lounges mentioned on the airport website [here](http://www.bengaluruairport.com/airportInformation/lounges.jspx?_afrLoop=2063116036005188&_afrWindowMode=0&_adf.ctrl-state=x4gpvrunl_194), are all in the departures area, which means you can only use them if you have a connection. Alternatively, you can just book the hotel a day earlier and ask if you can check-in earlier. If you book a hotel close to the airport, I'd imagine they will be used to early check-ins.

Comment: If OP is going to book a hotel _a day earlier_ (as you suggest) then they would rather have to ask about **late** check-in (very late one), not _early_ check-in. A "day earlier" means that hotel stays starts the previous day. If asking about earlier check-in then there is no point in booking another hotel. OP can ask about the same in their original hotel (or I don't understand your answer).